# Use Putty within command prompt

Tags: putty

When i try this command in my windows cmd

```
putty.exe -ssh user1@244.60.212.17 -pw spenter11
```

It opens the Putty GUI when I want it to login from my windows cmd prompt itself.

Any help how can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 4):

You are not using the right application, the one you want to use instead is `plink`. `putty` itself *is* the terminal window (something like the GUI around `plink`)

```
plink.exe user1@server -pw password
```

Read more about it here: http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.58/htmldoc/Chapter7.html

Comment: I wish to use ssh. therefore plink may not help. Will it ?

Comment: `plink` implements the ssh-client-protocol. i do not understand your statement.